# UIWebView acts weird on iOS9

Tags: ios, webview, uiwebview, ios9

I have a UIWebView that displays an HTML page that it receives from the server as NSData.

Starting with iOS 9 the UIWebView sometimes shows the HTML as usual and sometimes it renders the HTML as a very small page.

Is this a known issue on iOS9?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add width=device-width to your viewport meta tag on beta4 and later it seems.

This seems like quite a regression from iOS9 beta 3.

Answer (score 0):

Some css attributes doesn't work in iOS9 but works in iOS8
for my case, i removed css attribute:

```
direction:rtl
```

then the existing layout worked fine